# How do I filter file names out of a SQLite dump?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, string, filter

I'm trying to filter out all file names from an SQLite text dump using Ruby. I'm not very handy/familiar with regex and need a way to read, and write to a file, another dump of image files that are within the SQLite dump. I can filter out everything except stuff like this:

```
VALUES(3,5,1,43,'/images/e/e5/Folder%2FOrders%2FFinding_Orders%2FView_orders3.JPG','1415',NULL);
```

and this:

```
src="/images/9/94/folder%2FGraph.JPG"
```

I can't figure out the easiest way to filter through this. I've tried using split and other functions, but instead of splitting the string into an array by the character specified, it just removed the character.

Comment: What do you want filter exactly? Any more sample input/output?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Extract a list of the image paths? How did your image paths come to look like that? It looks like they are (partially) url encoded. If you want to decode them you can do `URI.decode(image_path)`.

Comment: Specifically, I want to 'extract' the file name from the statements above. Say I have src="/images/9/94/folder%2FGraph.JPG", I want folder%2FGraph.JPG to be extracted out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `.gsub('%2', ' ')` the %2 with a space, while quoted, it should be fine.
Split does remove the character that is being split, though.  So you may not want to do that, or if you do, you may want to use the `Array#join` method with the argument of the character you split with to put it back in.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to 'extract' the file name from the statements above. Say I have src="/images/9/94/folder%2FGraph.JPG", I want folder%2FGraph.JPG to be extracted out.

If you want to extract what is inside the `src` parameter:

```
foo = 'src="/images/9/94/folder%2FGraph.JPG"'
foo[/^src="(.+)"/, 1]
=> "/images/9/94/folder%2FGraph.JPG"
```

That returns a string without the surrounding parenthesis.

Here's how to do the first one:

```
bar = "VALUES(3,5,1,43,'/images/e/e5/Folder%2FOrders%2FFinding_Orders%2FView_orders3.JPG','1415',NULL);"
bar.split(',')[4][1..-2]
=> "/images/e/e5/Folder%2FOrders%2FFinding_Orders%2FView_orders3.JPG"
```

Not everything in programming is a regex problem. Somethings, actually, in my opinion, most things, are not candidates for a pattern. For instance, the first example could be written:

```
foo.split('=')[1][1..-2]
```

and the second:

```
bar[/'(.+?)'/, 1]
```

The idea is to use whichever is most clean and clear and understandable.

---

If all you want is the filename, then use a method designed to return only the filename.

Use one of the above and pass its output to [`File.basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-basename). `Filename.basename` returns only the filename and extension.

Comment: I don't want the path, I need to get rid of the path and unwanted characters. As stated above, I literally just want the file names extracted. I believe I found a solution though using split("").last and split("").first. The first and last option provide me with the strings I actually wanted versus just removing the strings from the string.